# How to check a string for a given format using PHP?

Tags: php, string, match

I have many headlines in my project like:

```
00.00.2014 - Headline Description e.t.c.
```

I want to check with php if the given strings contain the format `00.00.0000 -` in front. The part after the `-` doesn't matter.

Can someone help me with something like:

```
$format = '00.00.0000 -';

if ($string MATCHES $format IN FRONT) {
    // ...some code...
}
```

Comment: i would ask you what you had tried, but i can guess waht the answer to that would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s\-\s.*$/", $string) === 1) {
    // $string matches!
}
```

Explanation:

- `^` is "the beginning of the string"
- `\d` is any digit (0, 1, 2, ..., 9)
- `{n}` means "repeated n times"
- `\.` is a dot
- `\s` is a space
- `\-` is a minus sign
- `.` is "any single character"
- `*` means "repeated 0 or more times`
- `$` means "end of the string"

Comment: Wow aint that some wizardry. Thanks for the explanation! Good answer.

Comment: exactly what i needed and thx for the explanation of the preg_macth function. no its clear!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a dev environment to test this out on but i'll give you some psuedocode:

I'm unsure of the context, but you can test this function on any given STRING:

Function:

```
 Boolean hasCorrectFormat($myString){

         //Here take the string and cut it into a char array.

         $charArray = str_split($myString); 

         //This will give you a char array. Compare the first 12 elements of this
         //array to see if they are correct. If its supposed to be number make
         //sure it is, if its supposed to be a "." make sure it is..etc
         //"00.00.0000 -" is 12 characters. 

         if(!isNumeric(charArray[0])){
             return false;
          }
          else if(!isNumeric(charArray[1])){
               return false;
          }
          else if(charArray[2] != "."){
               return false;
          }
        //so on and so forth.....
           else {return true}
    }
```

Like i said i can't test this, and i can almost guarantee you this code wont run. This should give you the logic involved though.

Edit: also i wrote this assuming you dont literally mean "00.00.0000" but rather "xx.xx.xxxx" x being any number 0-9. If you need to make sure it is literally zeros then just cut your string to be the first ten chars and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. Something like this:

```
if (strpos($string,'00.00.0000 -') !== true) {
//some code
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the example: `00.00.2014 - Headline Description e.t.c.`

Comment: In case you didn't notice and change it yourself, I mistakingly set `false` instead of `true`. It's now corrected. But @wil93 's solutions is better.